# I want to write icon names inside the paths of images <img source=""> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Dark Sky API to get weather information and icon parameter gives me cloudy, partly-cloudy, sunny etc. I saved icon images same name with icon names in the folder. I want to write this parameter inside the source path like

```
 <img src="..\..\icon\weather\  $forecast.weatherDays[0].icon .png" height="300vh" width="300vw">
```

weather.html

```
  <div id="day1"> <div id="icon"></div> </div>
 <div id="day2"> <div id="icon"></div> </div>
```

weatherManager.js

```
document.querySelector("#day1 #icon").innerHTML=forecast.weatherDays[0].icon;
document.querySelector("#day2 #icon").innerHTML=forecast.weatherDays[0].icon;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what is forecast.weatherDays[0].icon; ???

Comment: It gives me icon names from database like "partly-cloudy"

Comment: Please check the solution provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the image inside the div using the following code:

```js
var forecast = {};
forecast.weatherDays = [];

forecast.weatherDays[0]= { icon :'partly-cloudy'};
forecast.weatherDays[1]= { icon :'image8-2'};

//console.log(forecast.weatherDays)

document.querySelector("#day1 #icon").innerHTML= '<img src="..\\..\\icon\\weather\\'+forecast.weatherDays[0].icon+'.png" height="300vh" width="300vw">';

 document.querySelector("#day2 #icon").innerHTML= '<img src="https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/'+forecast.weatherDays[1].icon+'.jpg" height="300vh" width="300vw">';
```

```html
 <div id="day1"> <div id="icon"></div> </div>

 <div id="day2"> <div id="icon"></div> </div>
```